# Calculating correlation between points where each points has a timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statsmodels

I could use some advice how to make a faster code to my problem. I'm looking into how to calculate the correlation between points in space (X,Y,Z) where for each point I have velocity data over time and ideally I would like for each point P1 to calculate the velocity correlation with all other points.

In the end I would like to have a matrix that for each pair of coordinates (X1,Y1,Z1), (X2,Y2,Z2) I get the Pearson correlation coefficient. I'm not entirely sure how to organize this best in python. What I have done so far is that I defined lines of points in different directions and for each line I calculate the correlation between points. This works for the analysis but I end up doing loops that takes a very long time to execute and I think it would be nice to instead just calculate the correlation between all points. Right now I'm using pandas DataFrame and statsmodels to do the correlation (stats.pearsonr(point_X_time.Vx, point_Y_time.Vx) which works but I don't know how to parallelize it efficiently.

I have all the data now in a DataFrame where the head looks like:

```
    Velocity      X  Y      Z   Time  
0 -12.125850  2.036  0  1.172  10.42
1 -12.516033  2.036  0  1.164  10.42
2 -11.816067  2.028  0  1.172  10.42
3 -10.722124  2.020  0  1.180  10.42
4 -10.628474  2.012  0  1.188  10.42
```

and the number of rows is ~300 000 rows but could easily be increased if the code would be faster.

Comment: Do all the points in space have all the time points?

Comment: Yes all points have the same number of time points so they are sampled with same frequency and same start and end time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

```
groups = df.groupby(["X", "Y", "Z"])
```

You group the data by the points in space.

Than you iterate through all the combinations of points and calculate the correlation

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
for combinations in itertools.combinations(groups.groups.keys(),2):
    first = groups.get_group(combinations[0])["Velocity"]
    second = groups.get_group(combinations[1])["Velocity"]
    if len(first) == len(second):
        print(f"{combinations} {np.corrcoef(first, second)[0,1]:.2f}")
```

**Solution 2:**

```
df["cc"] = df.groupby(["X", "Y", "Z"]).cumcount()
df.set_index(["cc","X", "Y", "Z"])
df.unstack(level=[1,2,3])["Velocity"].corr()
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestion how to store the resulting data best in an object for example DataFrame? I'm not sure how to store the "pair point results" best.

Comment: I added another solution which returns a data-frame plus no iteration.

Comment: Solution 2 works great! Just with the minor change of adding inplace=True i.e. df.set_index(["cc","X", "Y", "Z"], inplace=True)
I'm impressed that it does it all in 3 lines of code.

Now the correlation (I think) will be calculated twice both so for a pair of points P1 and P2 it will calculate corr(P1,P2) and corr(P2,P1) however corr(P1,P2)=corr(P2,P1). Is there a way to avoid this double calculation?

For the final analysis I want for each point check how far the distance/points is until corr drops below a certain threshold but I'm not sure how to do so on the obtained DataFrame.

Comment: The corr does pairwise, you would need to iterate through the combinations like in the first solution, this is probably slower to be honest.

Comment: Don't understand what exactly you want with the final analysis? Maybe accept this answer and ask another q?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have now done that in a new questions where I try to reformulate and make the question more clear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70418796/correlation-drop-between-points-where-each-point-has-a-timeseries